# three divs not aligned correctly

Tags: css

i have a problem in aligning the div's **vertically**,what should be problem?

here is my html code

```
 <div class="recentProfiles">
<div class="profiles" id="profile1">
</div>
<div class="profiles" id="profile2">
</div>
<div class="profiles" id="profile3">
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.recentProfiles
{
width:950px;
height:200px;
border:2px dotted green;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:10px;
} 
.profiles
{
width:300px;
height:190px;
border:2px dotted black;
}
#profile1
{
float:left;
clear:both;
position:relative;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
 }
#profile2
{
position:relative;
margin-left:310px;
margin-top:5px;    
}
#profile3
{
position:relative;
margin-left:620px;
margin-top:5px;
}
```

i want the three div's to be aligned vertically together inside the parent, here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/yoyo/pen/AvJqI)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/irfJL

Comment: Do you really mean vertical? Your example looks more like you mean *horizontal*.

Comment: ya sorry its horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of your margins. If you take `clear:both` off `profile1` and then add `float: left` onto all profiles, then take off those margins.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WC5gT/

Comment: @Jacob It seems someone else had updated that codepen. Moved it to fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need so many redundant codes to achieve like what you describe, just do:

```
.recentProfiles
{
    width:300px;
    border:2px dotted green;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.profiles
{
    width:300px;
    height:190px;
    border:2px dotted black;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VvqXF/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float:left` on `class` profiles and then no `margin` on profile1, profile2, profile3

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rK38V/

Answer (score 0):

Have all the boxes float left (`float: left`) and remove all margin properties, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2ABmU/

Answer (score 0):

You get the idea of float wrong. Here's the new code: http://cdpn.io/AvJqI

**HTML**

```
  <div class="recentProfiles">

    <div class="profiles" id="profile1">
    </div>
    <div class="profiles" id="profile2">
    </div>
    <div class="profiles" id="profile3">
    </div>
    <div class="floatClear"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.recentProfiles
{
width:950px;
height:200px;
border:2px dotted green;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:10px;

}
.profiles
{
width:300px;
height:190px;
border:2px dotted black;

}
#profile1
{
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;

}
#profile2
{
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:5px;

}
#profile3
{
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:5px;
}

.floatClear {
  clear: both;
}
```